# ¿Cómo puedo obtener una lista de una base de datos y cambiar su orden?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Quiero mostrar en pantalla todos los elementos de una lista dentro de una base de datos para ello hago esto:

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_name');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //Obtengo los posts

?>

<div id="list">
<ul id="list ul">
</ul>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que muestre cada resultado en un `<li>` diferente? y ¿es posible mostrarlos en un orden aleatorio?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes imprimir un resultado de consulta usando el mismo PHP.
Si agregas el PHP entre el body, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Ejemplo:

```
$resultadoConsulta = [1,2,3,4,5];
echo "<div id='list'>";
foreach($resultadoConsulta as $r){
  echo "<ul id='list ul'>".$r."</ul>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Esto lo que hará será imprimir un HTML del siguiente modo:

```html
<body>
  <div id="list">
    <ul id="list ul">1</ul>
    <ul id="list ul">2</ul>
    <ul id="list ul">3</ul>
    <ul id="list ul">4</ul>
    <ul id="list ul">5</ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Ahora, si quieres alterar el orden de la lista, basta con desordenar el array devuelto.

```
<?php
$arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];
shuffle($arreglo);
var_dump($arreglo);
?>
-> Salida: 5,2,4,1,3
```